# Powershell script to automate azure linux VM backup and restore from azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-backup-vault

I tried multiple powershell script to do azure VM backup and restore but none of them are seems working or not so effective. Could any one please share the powershell script to create backup of VM and restore in azure via azure devops pipeline.

PowerShell Script:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Written By John Lewis
email: jonos@live.com
Ver 1.1

v 1.2 updates - minor fixes
v 1.1 updates - Added Pre-Checks
v 1.0 updates - RTM

Deploys Azure Backup Vault and configures Azure VMs to leverage vault. Provides automated restore to new VM.

.PARAMETER Action

.PARAMETER backupvmname

.PARAMETER backupvmrg

.PARAMETER rg

.PARAMETER policyname

.PARAMETER containertype

.PARAMETER Location

.PARAMETER wrkloadtype

.PARAMETER vaultname

.PARAMETER createvmname

.PARAMETER createvmrg

.PARAMETER vaultrg

.PARAMETER vnet

.PARAMETER vnetrg

.PARAMETER createvmsubnet


.EXAMPLE
.\AZRM-VMBackup.ps1 -csvimport -csvfile C:\temp\backupservers.csv
.EXAMPLE
.\AZRM-VMBackup.ps1 -action createpolicy -vaultname myvault -vaultrg myres -policyname mypolicy
.EXAMPLE
.\AZRM-VMBackup.ps1 -action createvault -vaultname myvault -vaultrg myres
.EXAMPLE
.\AZRM-VMBackup.ps1 -action addvmcreatevault -backupvmname myvm -backupvmrg myres -vaultname myvault -vaultrg myres
.EXAMPLE
.\AZRM-VMBackup.ps1 -action restorevm -createvmname myvm -createvmrg myres -vaultrg backuprg -vaultname myvaultname -vnet vnet -vnetrg myvnetrg
#>

[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'default')]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[ValidateSet("createpolicy","createvault","addvmcreatevault","addvmtovault","restorevm","executebackup","getstatus")]
[string]
$Action = 'createvault',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$vaultrg = "vault",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$storeagerg = $createvmrg,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[string]
$location = "East US",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$vaultname = "vault",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$backupvmname = '',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$backupvmrg = '',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[string]
$backupvmlocation = $location,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$createvmname = '',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$createvmrg = '',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[string]
$createvmlocation = $location,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true,Position=4)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[Alias("createvmvnet")]
[string]
$VNetName = 'vnet',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[string]
$vnetrg = $createvmrg,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$policyname = 'policy',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$containertype = 'AzureVM',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$wrkloadtype = 'AzureVM',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$provider = "Microsoft.RecoveryServices",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$Profile = "profile",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$csvfile = -join $workfolder + "\azrm-vmbackup.csv",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[Alias("csv")]
[switch]
$csvimport,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[string]
$GenerateName = -join ((65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count 6 | % {[char]$_}) + "rmp",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[string]
$StorageName = $createvmname + 'str',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateSet("Standard_LRS","Standard_GRS")]
[string]
$StorageType = 'Standard_GRS',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[Alias("int1")]
[string]
$InterfaceName1 = $createvmname + '_nic1',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[Alias("int2")]
[string]
$InterfaceName2 = $createvmname + "_nic2",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$SubscriptionID = '',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
$TenantID = '',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateSet("InProgress","Completed")]
[string]
$status = 'InProgress',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateRange(0,8)]
[ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
[Alias("createvmsubnet")]
[Int]
$Subnet1 = 4

    )
$workfolder = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$ProfileFile = $workfolder+'\'+$profile+'.json'
$restorejson = $workfolder+'\'+ 'config.json'

Function validate-profile {
$comparedate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$fileexist = Test-Path $ProfileFile -NewerThan $comparedate
  if($fileexist)
  {
  $az = Import-AzureRmContext -Path $ProfileFile
      $subid = $az.Context.Subscription.Id

    Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subid | Out-Null
        Write-Host "Using $ProfileFile"
  }
  else
  {
  Write-Host "Please enter your credentials"
  Add-AzureRmAccount
  Save-AzureRmContext -Path $ProfileFile -Force
  Write-Host "Saved Profile to $ProfileFile"
  exit
  }
}

Function csv-run {
param(
[string] $csvin = $csvfile
)
    $GetPath = test-path -Path $csvin
    if(!$csvin)
    {exit}
    else {
    Write-Host $GetPath "File Exists"
import-csv -Path $csvin -Delimiter ',' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object{.\AZRM-VMBackup.ps1 -VMName $_.VMName -rg $_.rg -Action $_.Action -vmrg $_.vmrg -servaultname $_.servaultname }
}
}

Function Check-StorageName
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$StorageName  = $StorageName
    )

    $checkname =  Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name $StorageName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameAvailable
if($checkname -ne 'False') {
    Write-Host "Storage Account Found..."
    $script:StorageNameVerified = $StorageName.ToLower()
    }
    else
        {
        $script:StorageNameVerified = $StorageName.ToLower()
        Create-Storage
        }
}

#region Create Storage
Function Create-Storage {
        param(
        [string]$StorageName = $script:StorageNameVerified,
        [string]$StorageType = $StorageType,
        [string]$containerName = 'vhds',
        [string]$Location = $Location,
        [string]$storeagerg = $storeagerg
        )
        Write-Host "Starting Storage Creation..."
        $script:StorageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $storeagerg -Name $StorageName.ToLower() -Type $StorageType -Location $Location -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Host "Completed Storage Creation" -ForegroundColor White
            }

Function Check-Vnet {
$vnetexists = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetrg -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$vnetexists)
    { 
    Write-Host "$VNetName does not exists!"
        break
    }
    else
        { $existvnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetrg

            $addspace = $existvnet.AddressSpace | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AddressPrefixes
            $namespace = $existvnet.Name
            $existvnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetrg
            $addsubnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $existvnet

            $sub = $addsubnet.AddressPrefix
            $subname = $addsubnet.Name
            $nsg = $addsubnet.NetworkSecurityGroup
            $subnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $existvnet | ft Name,AddressPrefix -AutoSize -Wrap -HideTableHeaders
            Write-Host "                                                               "
            Write-Host "VNET CONFIGURATION - Existing VNET" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Write-Host "                                                               "
            Write-Host "Active VNET: $VnetName in resource group $vnetrg"
            Write-Host "Address Space: $addspace "
            Write-Host "Subnet Ranges: $sub "
            Write-Host "Subnet Names: $subname "
        }
}

Function Check-VaultExists {
$vaultexists = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname -ResourceGroupName $vaultrg -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$vaultexists)
    { 
    Write-Host "Specified vault $vaultname does not exist!" -ForegroundColor Red
        break
    }

}

function Check-VaultNullValues {
if(!$vaultrg) {
Write-Host "Please select -vaultrg"  -ForegroundColor Red
exit
}
    elseif(!$vaultname) {
    Write-Host "Please Enter -vaultname" -ForegroundColor Red
    exit
    }
                elseif(!$Location) {
                Write-Host "Please Enter -Location" -ForegroundColor Red
                exit
                }

}

function Check-BackupVMNullValues {
if(!$backupvmrg) {
Write-Host "Please select -backupvmrg"  -ForegroundColor Red
exit
}
    elseif(!$backupvmname) {
    Write-Host "Please Enter -backupvmname" -ForegroundColor Red
    exit
    }
                elseif(!$Location) {
                Write-Host "Please Enter -Location" -ForegroundColor Red
                exit
                }

}

function Check-CreateVMNullValues {
if(!$createvmrg) {
Write-Host "Please select -createvmrg"  -ForegroundColor Red
exit
}
    elseif(!$createvmname) {
    Write-Host "Please Enter -createvmname" -ForegroundColor Red
    exit
    }
        if(!$backupvmrg) {
        Write-Host "Please select -backupvmrg"  -ForegroundColor Red
        exit
        }
        elseif(!$backupvmname) {
        Write-Host "Please Enter -backupvmname" -ForegroundColor Red
        exit
        }
                elseif(!$Location) {
                Write-Host "Please Enter -Location" -ForegroundColor Red
                exit
                }

}


function Check-StorageNullValues {
if(!$storeagerg) {
Write-Host "Please select -storage"  -ForegroundColor Red
exit
}
    elseif(!$StorageName) {
    Write-Host "Please Enter -createvmname" -ForegroundColor Red
    exit
    }
                elseif(!$Location) {
                Write-Host "Please Enter -Location" -ForegroundColor Red
                exit
                }

}

function Check-VNETNullValues {
if(!$vnetrg) {
Write-Host "Please select -vnetrg"  -ForegroundColor Red
exit
}
    elseif(!$VNetName) {
    Write-Host "Please Enter -vnetname" -ForegroundColor Red
    exit
    }
                elseif(!$Location) {
                Write-Host "Please Enter -Location" -ForegroundColor Red
                exit
                }

}


function Reg-Provider {
param($provider = $provider)
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace $provider
}

Function Provision-RG
{
    Param(
        [string]$rg = $vaultrg
    )
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rg -Location $Location –Confirm:$false -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Out-Null
}

Function Check-VMExists {
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]
    $Location = $Location,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]
    $rg = $backupvmrg,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]
    $VMName = $backupvmname
    )
    $extvm = Get-AzureRmVm -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $rg -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$extvm)
{
    Write-Host "$VMName does not exist, please verify the VM exists" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Break
}

 else {Write-Host "Restoration VM found" -ForegroundColor Green}
 
} #
#endregion




Function Configure-Backup {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]
        $action = $action
    )
switch ($action)
    {
        "createvault" {
                Check-VaultNullValues
                Write-Host "Creating new Backup Vault $vaultname"
                Write-Config
                Provision-RG
                Create-Vault
                Get-CurrentPolicies
                Create-Policy
                Write-Completion
}
        "createpolicy" {
                Write-Host "Creating new Policy"
                Write-Config
                Check-VaultExists
                Get-CurrentPolicies
                Create-Policy
                Write-Completion
        }
        "addvmtovault" {
                Check-VMExists
                Check-VaultExists
                Write-Host "Adding VM $backupvmname to $vaultname"
                Write-Config
                Get-CurrentPolicies
                AddVM-Vault
                Write-Completion
        }
        "executebackup" {
                Write-Host "Executing backup of $backupvmname to $vaultname"
                Check-VMExists
                Write-Config
                Check-BackupVMNullValues
                Get-CurrentPolicies
                TriggerBackup-Vault
                Write-Completion
        }
        "addvmcreatevault" {
            Check-VaultNullValues
            Write-Host "Creating new Backup Vault $vaultname"
            Write-Config
            Provision-RG
            Create-Vault
            Create-Policy
            Check-BackupVMNullValues
            Check-VaultExists
            Check-VMExists
            Write-Host "Adding VM $backupvmname to $vaultname"
            Get-CurrentPolicies
            AddVM-Vault
            Write-Completion
        }
        "restorevm" {
            Check-CreateVMNullValues
            Check-VNETNullValues
            Check-Vnet
            Check-StorageNullValues
            Check-VMExists
            Check-StorageName
            Write-Host "Restoring VM Backup from $backupvmname to $createvmname"
            Write-Config
            Restore-VMVHD
            Create-VM
            Write-Completion
        }
        "getstatus" {
                Write-Host "Obtaining current job information"
                Get-JobProgress
        }
        default{"An unsupported backup command was used"}
    }
    exit
}

Function Get-JobProgress {
    param(
        $status = $status

    )

Get-AzureRmRecoveryservicesBackupJob –Status $status
}

function Create-Vault {
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $vaultrg -Location $Location –Confirm:$false -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Out-Null
New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname -ResourceGroupName $vaultrg -Location $location
$vault1 = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault –Name $vaultname
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProperties  -Vault $vault1 -BackupStorageRedundancy GeoRedundant
}

function Get-Context {
param($vaultname = $vaultname)
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
}

function Get-CurrentPolicies {
param(
$vaultname = $vaultname,
$wrkloadtype = $wrkloadtype
)
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$schPol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupSchedulePolicyObject -WorkloadType $wrkloadtype
$retPol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRetentionPolicyObject -WorkloadType $wrkloadtype
}

function Create-Policy {
param(
$vaultname = $vaultname,
$policyname = $policyname,
$wrkloadtype = $wrkloadtype
)
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$schPol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupSchedulePolicyObject -WorkloadType $wrkloadtype
$retPol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRetentionPolicyObject -WorkloadType $wrkloadtype
New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $policyname -WorkloadType $wrkloadtype -RetentionPolicy $retPol -SchedulePolicy $schPol -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue
$script:pol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $policyname
}

function Modify-Policy {
param(
$vaultname = $vaultname,
$policyname = $policyname,
$wrkloadtype = $wrkloadtype
)

$retPol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRetentionPolicyObject -WorkloadType "AzureVM"
$retPol.DailySchedule.DurationCountInDays = 365
$pol= Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $policyname
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Policy $pol  -RetentionPolicy $RetPol
}

function TriggerBackup-Vault {
param(
$vaultname = $vaultname,
$backupvmname = $backupvmname,
$containertype = "AzureVM"
)
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$namedContainer = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType $containertype -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName $backupvmname
$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $namedContainer -WorkloadType "AzureVM"
$job = Backup-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Item $item
}

function AddVM-Vault {
param(
$vaultname = $vaultname,
$backupvmname = $backupvmname,
$containertype = "AzureVM",
$vaultrg = $backupvmrg,
$policyname = $policyname
)
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$script:pol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $policyname
Enable-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Policy $script:pol -Name $backupvmname -ResourceGroupName $vaultrg
$namedContainer = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType $containertype -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName $backupvmname
$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $namedContainer -WorkloadType "AzureVM"
$job = Backup-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Item $item
$job
}

Function Get-RestorePoint {
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$endDate = Get-Date
$rp = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $backupitem -StartDate $startdate.ToUniversalTime() -EndDate $enddate.ToUniversalTime()
$rp[0]
}

Function Write-Config {
param(

)

Write-Host "                                                               "
$time = " Start Time " + (Get-Date -UFormat "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
Write-Host BACKUP/RESTORE CONFIGURATION - $time -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "                                                               "
Write-Host "Operation: $Action " -ForegroundColor White
Write-Host "                                                               "
}

Function Write-Completion {
param(

)

Write-Host "                                                               "
$time = " End Time " + (Get-Date -UFormat "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
Write-Host BACKUP/RESTORE CONFIGURATION - $time -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "                                                               "
Write-Host "Completed operation: $Action " -ForegroundColor White
Write-Host "                                                               "
}


function Restore-VMVHD {
param(
$vaultname = $vaultname,
$storeagerg = $storeagerg,
$StorageName = $script:StorageNameVerified,
$backupvmname = $backupvmname

)
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$namedContainer = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer  -ContainerType "AzureVM" –Status "Registered" -FriendlyName $backupvmname -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop
$backupitem = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem –Container $namedContainer  –WorkloadType "AzureVM" -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$endDate = Get-Date
$rp = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $backupitem -StartDate $startdate.ToUniversalTime() -EndDate $enddate.ToUniversalTime() -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop -InformationAction SilentlyContinue
$rp[0]
Write-Host "Preparing Restore Job"
$restorejob = Restore-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -RecoveryPoint $rp[0] -StorageAccountName $StorageName -StorageAccountResourceGroupName $storeagerg -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop
Wait-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupJob -Job $restorejob -Timeout 43200 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop
Write-Host "Restore Job Running"
$script:restorejob = $restorejob
$restorejob = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupJob -Job $script:restorejob -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop
$JobDetails = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupJobDetails -Job $restorejob -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop
$properties = $JobDetails.properties
$properties
$storageAccountName = $properties["Target Storage Account Name"]
$containerName = $properties["Config Blob Container Name"]
$blobName = $properties["Config Blob Name"]

Write-Host $storageAccountName
Write-Host $blobName
Write-Host $containerName

Write-Host "Completed restore job"
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -Name $storageaccountname -ResourceGroupName $storeagerg

$destination_path = $restorejson

Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Destination $destination_path -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue -Force -Confirm:$false
$obj = ((Get-Content -Path $destination_path -Raw -Encoding Unicode)).TrimEnd([char]0x00) | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host "Exported json configuration file to $destination_path"
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMSize $obj.'properties.hardwareProfile'.vmSize -VMName $createvmname -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -InformationAction SilentlyContinue
Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name "osdisk" -VhdUri $obj.'properties.StorageProfile'.osDisk.vhd.Uri -CreateOption "Attach" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop -InformationAction SilentlyContinue
$vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType = $obj.'properties.StorageProfile'.OsDisk.OsType
foreach($dd in $obj.'properties.StorageProfile'.DataDisks)
 {
 $vm = Add-AzureRmVMDataDisk -VM $vm -Name "datadisk1" -VhdUri $dd.vhd.Uri -DiskSizeInGB 128 -Lun $dd.Lun -CreateOption "Attach"
 }
Write-Host "Completed data disk configuration"
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $InterfaceName1 -ResourceGroupName $createvmrg -Location $createvmlocation -AllocationMethod "Dynamic" –Confirm:$false -WarningAction SilentlyContinue  -ErrorAction Stop -Force -InformationAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "Completed public ip creation"
$script:VNet = Get-AzureRMVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetrg | Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork
$script:Interface1 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName1 -ResourceGroupName $createvmrg -Location $createvmlocation -SubnetId $VNet.Subnets[$Subnet1].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id –Confirm:$false -WarningAction SilentlyContinue  -ErrorAction Stop -EnableIPForwarding -Force
$script:VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $script:Interface1.Id -Primary -WarningAction SilentlyContinue  -ErrorAction Stop -InformationAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "Completed vm prep"
}

Function Login-AddAzureRmProfile
{
Add-AzureRmAccount -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

}

Function Create-VM
{
    Write-Host "Creating VM"
    New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $createvmrg -Location $createvmlocation -VM $script:VirtualMachine
}


try {
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Location $Location -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
}
catch {
    Write-Host -foregroundcolor Yellow `
    "User has not authenticated, use Add-AzureRmAccount or $($_.Exception.Message)"; `
    Login-AddAzureRmProfile
}


Reg-Provider

if($csvimport) {
    try {
    csv-run
    }
    catch {
    Write-Host -foregroundcolor Yellow `
    "$($_.Exception.Message)"; `
    break
    }
}

try {
    Configure-Backup
    }
    catch {
    Write-Host -foregroundcolor Yellow `
    "$($_.Exception.Message)"; `
    break
    }
```

Error Message:

The below error is coming while I run from Run books automation account. provided runtime parameters to run the above script and left the value for CSVIMPORT parameter.

```
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
   at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderController.BindPositionalParametersInSet(UInt32 validParameterSets, Dictionary`2 nextPositionalParameters, CommandParameterInternal argument, ParameterBindingFlags flags, ParameterBindingException& bindingException)
   at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderController.BindPositionalParameters(Collection`1 unboundArguments, UInt32 validParameterSets, UInt32 defaultParameterSet, ParameterBindingException& outgoingBindingException)
   at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParametersNoValidation(Collection`1 arguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.BindCommandLineParameters()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoPrepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean incomingStream)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

Environments                                                                                           Context          
------------                                                                                           -------          
{[AzureCloud, AzureCloud], [AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureUSGovernment, AzureUSGovernment]} Microsoft.Azur...
A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Are you sure you want to register the provider 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$ResourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$ServicePrincipalName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$ServicePrincipalPass,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$SubscriptionId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$TenantId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$VMname,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$vaultname
    )

$targetVault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $vaultname
$targetVault.ID
Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -WorkloadType "AzureVM" -VaultId $targetVault.ID
Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultname | Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$policy = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $policyname
Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMname -Policy $policy
$backupcontainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -FriendlyName $VMname
$item = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $backupcontainer -WorkloadType "AzureVM"
$backupjob=Backup-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Item $item
echo $backupjob
#$Backupstatus=Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob
#Wait-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJob -Job $joblist[0] -Timeout 43200 -VaultId $targetVault.ID
Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob
$namedContainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer  -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName $VMname -VaultId $targetVault.ID
$backupitem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $namedContainer  -WorkloadType "AzureVM" -VaultId $targetVault.ID
echo "Please wait for backup to complete - Backup is in progress"
start-sleep -s 30
$joblist = Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob –Status "InProgress" -VaultId $targetVault.ID
$joblist[0]
while (!$rp.ContainerName) 
  { 
    $startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
    $endDate = Get-Date
    $rp = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $backupitem -StartDate $startdate.ToUniversalTime() -EndDate $enddate.ToUniversalTime() -VaultId $targetVault.ID
    start-sleep -s 30
    $rp[0]  
    Write-Host -NoNewline "Waiting 30 seconds for" $VMName "VM to backup" 
  }
Get-AzRecoveryservicesBackupJob
echo "Backup is completed successfully"
```

Comment: Is there any way that we can do VM backup using powershell script without backup policy?